# Convert vector with sets of values preceeded by "headers", to separate vectors

Tags: r

I have a vector with several sets of elements. Each set is preceded by a certain name, given by `"A"`, `"B"` and `"C"` as an example over here:

```
v1 <- c("A", letters[1:5], "B", letters[6:7], "C", letters[8:12])
v1
# [1] "A" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "B" "f" "g" "C" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l"
```

The position of the "headers" can be obtained by `grep`:

```
start <- grep("[ABC]", v1)
# [1]  1  7 10
```

How do I proceed from here to extract the three sets of elements as separate vectors with the preceding "headers" as their name?

```
"A" <- letters[1:5]
"B" <- letters[6:7]
"C" <- letters[8:12]

A
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
B
# [1] "f" "g"
C
# [1] "h" "i" "j" "k" "l"
```

---

**SOLUTION**

I hope the kind soul who provided an answer to this question (his id eluded me), but later deleted his answer and all of his comments can be contacted, and the answer reinstated, so that he can be duly rewarded with upvotes.

Contrary to my initial claim, which was caused by a misunderstanding, his answer DID provide a viable solution.

Here's the gist of it, from what I can recall:

```
end <- start-1
end <- end[-1]
end[length(end)+1] <- length(v1)

[1]  6  9 15

map2(start+1, end, ~v1[.x:.y]) %>% set_names(v1[start])
$A
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

$B
[1] "f" "g"

$C
[1] "h" "i" "j" "k" "l"
```

Comment: @Henrik, sorry to bother you, but could you help me check out who's the guy who posted and then deleted his answer to this question sometime ago? I would really like to give him credit for it.

Comment: Thanks, Henrik! @hrbrmstr, your answer did work, after all. I have edited my question to incorporate a solution based on your input. I hope you can reinstate your answer so that I can give you credit for it. Thank you!

Comment: Could someone tell me what is the function of the `~` in `~v1[.x:.y]` on the solution given above?